# WPF listbox removing item properly

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, listbox

Hi I am making an WPF application and have a problem with a `listbox/listview`, `MVVM` is implemented. I am creating a list of a class that is displayed on the `listbox` and I am editing the items through selecting an item in the `listbox`. The problem is when I am deleting an item it doesn't trigger `onpropertychanged` event to the UI, but is however working in the code, the values are right. When I close the window and reopens it then the list is updated, but not directly when the item is deleted, it never triggers `onpropertychanged` event for some reason.

It does work to just filter the quicknotelist like

```
quicknotelist = quicknotelist.where(x => x.id != selecteditem.id);
```

It works only once though and the UI updates however the `selecteditem` doesn't seem to work properly even though I am declaring

```
selecteditem = new quicknote() {*values*};
```

Part of relevant code, I am using `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
  private QuickNote selectedNote = new QuickNote();  // weeeeeee
    public QuickNote SelectedNote
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedNote;
        }
        set
        {
            if (SelectedNote != null)
            {
                selectedNote = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedNote");
                EnableEditNoteBox = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private List<QuickNote> quickNoteList = new List<QuickNote>();
    public List<QuickNote> QuickNoteList
    {
        get { return quickNoteList; }
        set { quickNoteList = value; OnPropertyChanged("QuickNoteList");  }
    }
```

here is the method that deletes the item

```
private void DeleteNote(object obj)
    {
        if (SelectedNote != null) 
        {
            QuickNoteList.Remove(SelectedNote); 
   // I want this to trigger       onpropertychanged without using myclasslist = newclasslist; since it messes up selecteditem to null.

         }
     }
```

heres the xaml part.

```
 <ListBox
    Width="713"
    Height="230"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNote, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding QuickNoteList,BindsDirectlyToSource=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Notes"
    Foreground="Black"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd leave a comment if I could. You should lookup ObservableCollection. I think QuickNoteList should be of this type.

Comment: I am aware of ObservableCollection but it ended up the same, using INotifypropertyChanged is pretty much like an ObservableCollection. I did try using ObservableCollection but it does pretty much the same.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42536/List-vs-ObservableCollection-vs-INotifyPropertyCha

Comment: @Lucy You should be using an `ObservableCollection`, which automatically tells bindings in the UI "this collection has changed, so redraw yourself" whenever an item is Added or Removed. Note that this is not the same as INotifyPropertyChanged, which only triggers when a property changes from one value to another. The second thing you are probably missing is it looks like you are creating a new QuickNote object for the selected id... this won't work because by default, WPF compares objects by Reference, so the reference to the QuickNote in your list is different than the newly created reference

Comment: What is QuickNote?

Comment: Implemented ObservableCollection and it ended up with the secondary problem that I mentioned. It works but only once, selecteditem will become null, and it stays null even after I do something like this after the remove method, SelectedNote = new Quicknote() {Values };

Comment: Should if (SelectedNote != null) be if (SelectedNote != value) ?

Comment: No, that is a check if a note of the listbox is selected, then the property gets the selecteditem, an empty check.

Comment: I'd still like to know what QuickNote is.

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt my previous comment relating to if (SelectedNote != null)  referred to the property setter. As coded, OnPropertyChanged will not fire if the value is currently null and is changed to non-null.

Comment: QuickNote is a class with properties such as a string and an id(guid). I am aware of that and working on it.

Comment: I have removal working with ObservableCollection and not list. Also, I assign QuickNoteList = new ObservableCollection<QuickNote>(); in the constructor. While it may work with a List you're setting quickNoteList rather than QuickNoteList so your  OnPropertyChanged("QuickNoteList") is not firing.

Comment: Incidentally, I also changed the condition to if (SelectedNote != value) in the the property setter.

Comment: I used ObservableCollection, but do you mean on the deletenote method with the if state? I can't really set null to value. Added quicknotelist to a new ObservableCollection on the constructor

Comment: In my VM constructor I have QuickNoteList = new ObservableCollection<QuickNote>(); In SelectedNote property setter I have                 if (SelectedNote != value)
                {
                    selectedNote = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedNote");
                    //EnableEditNoteBox = true;
                }